# Quickly toggling switch causes UI flicker (Firestore)

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase, react-redux-firebase

Performing two quick "switch toggles" causes a flicker because React-Native Switch updates the UI for second-switch element before Firestore DB completes the first switch update.

I have a collection of tasks, where each task has the following schema:

```
task : {
 shared: {
   sample_user_id_1: true,
   sample_user_id_2: false
 }
}
```

Because Firestore returns a full document snapshot (and not just a specific part of document that was updated), I see two solutions here to remove the flicker:
1) Only dispatch & pipe the change that was updated, essentially only listening to part of the document at a time (dispatch a state change independent of Redux-Firestore) eg:

```
if(newValue.shared[user_id_1] !== oldState.shared[user_id_1])
    dispatch(manualShareUpdate(user_id_1));
```

This solution does not seem scalable.

2) Change Data structure such that each "shared" bit is stored independently of other shared bits eg.

```
task : {
 id: task_1
}
```

New "task_shared" collection for each task, shared pair

```
task_shared : {
  task_id: sample_task_id
  user_id: sample_user_id,
  shared: true
}
```